# Visibility On and Off MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How to make a radio button by default checked..Here is my button..

```
  <%=Html.RadioButton("Method","1")%><label>Normal Method</label>
```

and also a div to be visible false..I had given like this, but no use..

```
 <div id="Normal" visible="false">
 <p>
 //............  
 </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("Method", "1", true) %>
```

or by setting `ViewData["Method"] = "1"` inside your controller action.

Remark: there's no such attribute as `visible="false"` on a `div`.

Comment: Thanks for radio button and what should i do for DIV Visibility.

Comment: What does the DIV visibility has to do with your question? If the DIV is to be hidden apply it some CSS class with display: none.

Comment: I am having 2 DIV's. While entering the page both should be in visible false.

Comment: for that i had given like this....."<div id="Normal" visible="false">
   <p>
      <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.NormalMethod)%>:&nbsp;
      <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), new { onChange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%> 
      <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyNameNM)%> 
   </p>
   </div>"

Comment: Well then apply to both divs `class="hidden"` where this class is defined like this: `.hidden { display: none; }` in your CSS file. @Sridhar R, I would really recommend you reading some basic tutorials about HTML and CSS before starting to work with ASP.NET MVC. That's basic stuff that you should know.